# Links não se alinham em cada div num Footer

Tags: html, css

Olá! Na parte do desenvolvimento de meu site (em HTML5, CSS3), me deparei com um problema nos links das seções do Footer, que ambos colocados dentro de tags `div` não se alinham verticalmente abaixo de cada seção, ocasionando colapso. Irei anexar uma imagem com a opção que almejo, e depois os códigos:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/V3xRcX7.png]

```css
footer {
    background-color: #0d1015;
    width: 980px;
    margin-top: 1.2em;
    border-top: 6px solid #ffcb08;
    clear: both;
}

#footer-sections {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
}

#footer-sections img {
    max-width: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.footer-title {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ebedf0;
    margin: 1em 15px;
}

.footer-link {
   display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<footer>
<div id="footer-sections">
<a href="index.html"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/yXnNKRi.png" alt="Logo Footer" title="Logo Footer"></a>
<div id="caixa-1" class="footer-title">SEÇÕES</div>
<div class="footer-link">
<a href="index.html">HOME</a>
<a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
<a href="history.html">HISTORY</a>
<a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
</div>
<div id="caixa-2" class="footer-title">SOUVENIRS</div>
<div class="footer-link">
<a href="index.html">HOME</a>
<a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
<a href="history.html">HISTORY</a>
<a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
</div>
<div id="caixa-3" class="footer-title">ESPECIAIS</div>
<div class="footer-link">
<a href="index.html">HOME</a>
<a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
<a href="history.html">HISTORY</a>
<a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que faltou uns espaçamentos e você fechou algumas DIVs incorretamente.
Tenta as seguintes mudanças no seu HTML:

```
<footer>
    <div id="footer-sections">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/yXnNKRi.png" alt="Logo Footer" title="Logo Footer"></a>
        <div id="caixa-1" class="footer-title">SEÇÕES<br/>
            <div class="footer-link">
                <a href="index.html">HOME</a><br/>
                <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a><br/>
                <a href="history.html">HISTORY</a><br/>
                <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="caixa-2" class="footer-title">SOUVENIRS<br/>
            <div class="footer-link">
                <a href="index.html">HOME</a><br/>
                <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a><br/>
                <a href="history.html">HISTORY</a><br/>
                <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="caixa-3" class="footer-title">ESPECIAIS<br/>
            <div class="footer-link">
                <a href="index.html">HOME</a><br/>
                <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a><br/>
                <a href="history.html">HISTORY</a><br/>
                <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: **@LeonVFX** Deu certo aqui, amigo! Posteriormente, farei mais algumas alterações nesses links para fins estéticos. Agradeço por me ajudar! Abraço.

Comment: De nada! Que bom que deu certo para você! :)